# How to pass a UserPrincipal with PrincipalContext inside ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory

I have the following code to connect to our AD :-

```
List<DomainContext> results = new List<DomainContext>();
string ADServerName = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADServerName"];

using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADServerName))
using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
{
```

The above worked on our Dev machine as the AD and the asp.net mvc were on the same machine. currently I need to connect to our staging AD which is on different machine. so I need to pass the AD service account (username & password) to the `PrincipalContext`. Can anyone advice? I read online that I need to use `UserPrincipal` as follow:-

```
public UserPrincipal(
    PrincipalContext context,
    string samAccountName,
    string password,
    bool enabled
)
```

but I am not sure how I can modify my code accordingly ?

Thanks

**EDIT**
I tried this to display only user that have brancjA or brachB inside their distinguished accounts:-

```
public List<DomainContext> GetADUsers(string term=null)
        {
            string[] types = new string[] { "BranchA", "BranchB" };
            List<DomainContext> results = new List<DomainContext>();
            string ADServerName = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADServerName"];
            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADServerName, "username", "password"))
            using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
            {
                var searchResults = searcher.FindAll();



                foreach (Principal p in searchResults)
                {
                   if ((term == null || p.SamAccountName.ToString().ToUpper().StartsWith(term.ToUpper())) && (types.Contains(p.DistinguishedName)))
```

but the result was that no users were returned. can you advice please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about creating the `PrincipalContext` and supplying specific credentials (username + password) in doing so?

Check out the [fabolous MSDN documentation on `PrincipalContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - freely available to **anyone** - use it!

As you can see, the `PrincipalContext` has several overloaded constructors to allow various scenarios:

[image]

You'll probably want to use [this constructor here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341016%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public PrincipalContext(
    ContextType contextType,
    string name,
    string userName,
    string password
)
```

This allows you to pass in a user name and a password to use for all your AD operations under this context.

**Update:** the follow-up question about returning only the "normal" users (and ignoring the "service accounts") - when you use a `PrincipalSearcher`, you can define a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
   // and with the first name (GivenName) of "Bruce" and a last name (Surname) of "Miller"
   UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
   qbeUser.GivenName = "Bruce";
   qbeUser.Surname = "Miller";

   // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
   PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

   // find all matches
   foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
   {
       // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
   }
}
```

Of course, depending on your need, you might want to specify other properties on that "query-by-example" user principal you create:

- `DisplayName` (typically: first name + space + last name)
- `SAM Account Name` - your Windows/AD account name
- `User Principal Name` - your "username@yourcompany.com" style name

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`. So really - you only need to find the proper way to express the criteria which distinguishes the "normal" users from the "service accounts" in your `PrincipalSearcher` and you should be able to do this just fine

**Update #2:** what I meant was something like this:

```
// create list to hold results
List<Principal> allNormalUsers = new List<Principal>();            

// first, search OU=BranchA
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADServerName, "OU=BranchA,OU=Users", "username", "password"))
using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
{
    allNormalUsers.AddRange(searcher.FindAll());
}

// after that, search OU=BranchB
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADServerName, "OU=BranchB,OU=Users", "username", "password"))
using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
{
    allNormalUsers.AddRange(searcher.FindAll());
}

// and now your "allNormalUsers" should contain all "normal" users from OU=BranchA 
// and from OU=BranchB
```

Comment: I tried this "using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADServerName, "username", "password"))". but this have returned all the users even the service accounts. so is there a way to filter the user list, to retrieve only actual users?

Comment: @JohnJohn: sure - what criteria distinguishes the "normal" users from the "service accounts" ?

Comment: they have something such as "OU=BranchA,OU=Users" as part of their distingued name.

Comment: @JohnJohn: are the "normal" users all inside a specific "container" (OU) and service accounts in another container? There's another overloaded constructor for the `PrincipalContext` which allows you to define in which **container** to search for those objects, e.g. you could search inside only `OU=Users` (and all it's subcontainers) if the service accounts are located elsewhere

Comment: I checked with our system admin and he mentioned that all users should have either OU=BranchA OR OU=BranchB .

Comment: @JohnJohn: so then you might need to do two searches, one in `OU=BranchA` and temporarily hold all the `UserPrincipal` objects returned, and then do a second search in `OU=BranchB` and merge those results into the first list - and then you have all your "normal" users

Comment: thanks a lot, can you check my edit please ? I tried filter users , but no users were returned.

Comment: @JohnJohn: updated my response again - see if that works for you

Comment: thanks. your approach is better as I will be retrieving only the necessary users. but for the current stage I wrote something such as  types.Any(p.DistinguishedName.ToLower().Contains). and it have done the filter , although I will be retrieving all users then do the filter.

Comment: @John- Please let me know, In username and password do we need to provide some admin username and password. Please help.